# Clearing textbox on focus not working- ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, textbox, focus

Here on SO, when you click on the search text box, the default text disappears.  I'm trying to implement similar functionality on a site.  Unfortunately, I can't get it to work in either FF or Chrome running on the localhost server.

The pageLoad method is defined as

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        MultiViewSearchOptions.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        txtKeywordSearch.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.value=string.Empty");

 }
```

and the textbox element is defined as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtKeywordSearch" runat="server" Width="175px">Click to search...</asp:TextBox>
```

I've tried several variations, whether `this.value=''`, or changing `onfocus` to `onclick`, but nothing works.  Is it due to running on the localhost, or whatnot?

**EDIT**

I solved the problem by inserting `OnClick="this.value=''"` inside the `asp:TextBox` declaration.  Works like a charm!

Comment: Works fine for me when I try it. Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: @Tim, I wasn't getting any Javascript errors.  In fact the txtKeywordSearch wasn't being accessed at any time in the Page_Load method.  See my edit for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the [jQuery watermark plug-ins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/watermark) (e.g. [this one](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)) or the Ajax Control Toolkit's [watermark extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx).

Comment: first, why do I need an external plugin when the functionality **should** be already implemented, and second, what is stopping this from working?  Can I look forward to more moments like this when working in ASP?

Comment: @Jason This is daily developer business for me; I expect something to work as _I_ think it has to, but this damn thing actually behaves just as it was designed by its developer ;-) Nothing special to ASP.NET in my opinion.